Unable to resolve remote name "..." Local IIS (local domains)
I've created 2 .NET Framework apps and want to check them in local domains
first - app.local (main app)
second - storage.local
I've created IIS WebSites also (set bindings for 80 and 443 ports) and put those domains to hosts file:
127.0.0.1 app.local
127.0.0.1 storage.local

I execute this code from main app app.local:
var url = "https://storage.local";
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = client.PostAsync(url + "/uploadnew", content).Result;
Console.WriteLine(message.StatusCode);

And got error Unable to resolve remote name "storage.local"
What am I doing wrong or what I forgot to add/setup?

Does this answer your question? How do I clear System.Net client DNS cache?

There's almost no way you have a valid certificate for the storage.local name, meaning even when you fix the name resolution the https protocol is unlikely to work.

@Alejandro I've set:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;```
but nothing has changed
